# angular2 routing not working because of slash in route parameters data

Tags: angular, routes, slash

Please help me on this.

I am trying to pass parameters in routing. But when my parameter value has slash symbol angular treating the text after the slash is another parameter and so my routing is not working.

{ path: 'resetpassword/:code', component: ResetPasswordComponent}

code value is some encrypted data , so the data generated by alogorithm has some slashes.

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to call the component? Or are you trying to call it from outside the application by navigating to xyz/resetpassword/some/value/with/slashes?

Comment: @Swetha I'm having the same issue. Did you find a way around it?

Comment: same issue here any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to encode your payload in some way. Try 
JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent()`/`decodeURIComponent()` or 
`Base58` (https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58).

JavaScript's `encodeURI()`/`decodeURI()` won't work because it does not encode slashes.

Obviously you could always replace the slashes by some other character yourself. However I find using a proper encoding mechanism to be a way more robust and maintainable approach.